# How to get only one marker in the Google Maps API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My code:

```
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
var map;
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

I've got every kilometer a new marker. How can I remove the other if I click it again?

Btw: read this :[Google Maps how to get to show only one marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232370/google-maps-how-to-get-to-show-only-one-marker)

Wanted to use it, but it doesn't work (in console: CurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option if you only ever want one marker, only create one and move it as required.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/57sL1826/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
var marker;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
    });
  } else {
    marker.setPosition(location);
  }
  if (!!infowindow && !!infowindow.close) {
    infowindow.close();
  }
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
```

try using this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    setMapOnAll(null);
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
}
```

So, you're deleting all the current markers on click and adding the new marker at x,y position

Comment: Thsi failure apears: newevent:227 Uncaught ReferenceError: setMapOnAll is not defined

Comment: Could you try removing setmaponall and use placeMarker(null)